# Using Lua as a Static lib in Application and a Lua Load module

Tags: c, lua

I am using Lua 5.3 as a Static lib in my application. I have a Lua module written as C Dll which also using Lua 5.3 as a static lib.

In the Loaded Module i am registering a function which returns a table of values. Table contains string as key and integer as value.

I am observing a random crash calling that function several times and the crash is showing on lua_gc.

I compiled lua as a dll with stub library and linked my application and the Lua Module using that. I don't observe crash after that.

So is it not recommended to have the Lua C module linking to Lua Statically?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is just do not do this.

Logn ansewer. 
1. You have to be sure your that both Lua libraries compiled with same flags (alignment, base type sizes).
2. Memory allocator has to be shared. If one Lua static lib allocate buffer other should be able free it) (With MSVC link with same dynamic runtime.
Do not link with static `msvcrt.lib`).

Other depend on OS.
On Windows you can export Lua API from your application and link module DLL with this executable. (Ru SciTE team do this)

But again just link with dynamic Lua library.

**Update**

There exists one more variant.
You can statically link all needed Lua modules as whell.
So it should be safe.